# error occurs in sending outlook mail using office36 smtp

Tags: python, outlook, office365, smtplib

I used

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', 587)
```

and tried this for login

```
smtp.login('********@amkor.co.kr', '********')
```

then this error message occured

> Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\mail.py", line 99, in 
> smtp.login('*******@amkor.co.kr', '********')

> File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 750, in login
> raise last_exception

> File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 739, in login
> (code, resp) = self.auth(

> File "C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\smtplib.py", line 662, in auth
> raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)

> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the federated STS URL does not support HTTPS. [SJ0PR03CA0214.namprd03.prod.outlook.com]')

Yet I could find little hint of what that means and how to fix it.
If you have any idea, please help me out.

** I added the full erro message and asterisked on my personal information. Thank you

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe it needs `SMTP_SSL` instead of `SMTP`

Comment: the SMTP_SSL is forbidden in my server I guess...